# Command option not found when using sudo

Tags: kubernetes-helm, sudo, permission-denied

I am trying to install the servecm plugin (https://github.com/jdolitsky/helm-servecm) for helm (https://helm.sh/), and following the installation steps I execute:

`helm plugin install https://github.com/jdolitsky/helm-servecm`

and then:

`helm servecm`

When I ran the second command, I got a permission denied error so I decided to run it with sudo, but when I run:

`sudo helm servecm`

I get the following error:

```
    $ sudo helm servecm
    Error: unknown command "servecm" for "helm"
    Run 'helm --help' for usage.
```

I've read in some other posts that I need to add the command to the sudo path, but in every case I've read is always for the first command, which is recognized, but I don't know how to do it for the servecm option.

If it is useful, the servecm.sh file is located at: `~/.local/share/helm/plugins/helm-servecm`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Helm plugins are stored in the user's home directory; since `sudo` switches users, the home directory will be different too.  This having been said, since Helm talks to a possibly-remote Kubernetes cluster, it's unlikely that local permissions are your problem and I don't think `sudo` will fix the underlying issue.

Answer (score 0):

the `permission denied` error that you are talking about may mean that you user account cannot access `~/.local/share/helm/plugins/helm-servecm` so try changing its permissions

```bash
chmod +rw ~/.local/share/helm/plugins/helm-servecm
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: There may be additional complications here. If you ran the command with `sudo` and it created the file, you now have a `root`-owned file in your personal home directory, which is a situation you would like to avoid. Probably retreat to a place where you can understand what `sudo` does, then try to sort this out.

Comment: @tripleee You're right I'll edit my answer

Comment: Thanks, I tried again but I get the same error as before

Comment: @Francisco What exactly is the error message ?

Comment: @SkwalExe I can't reproduce it right now but it was something like "servecm: permission denied", the same error that I get when something needs to be executed with sudo